# Need Logic to Add Counts

Tags: c#, regex

i have a following data in 3 sets.

```
EUR5-002,EUR10-000,
EUR20-001,EUR50-001,
EUR100-001,EUR200-000,
EUR500-000

EUR5-000,EUR10-000,
EUR20-002,EUR50-001,
EUR100-001,EUR200-000,
EUR500-000

EUR5-001,EUR10-001,
EUR20-002,EUR50-001,
EUR100-002,EUR200-003,
EUR500-000
```

Here EUR - CurrencyID and 5,10,20,50,100,200,500 are currency values. And the values after "-" is no of notes of the corresponding denomination.(EUR5-002, means 2 notes of 5 EUROs)

In my code I have read each set as string and added to List.

I need a logic in C# using regex or someother to add each individual denomination count from all 3 sets of data.

From the above data, I have to get the output as below.

```
EUR5-003,EUR10-001,
EUR20-005,EUR50-003,
EUR100-004,EUR200-003,
EUR500-000
```

Comment: which language/tool are you using?what have you tried

Comment: does each of the line always have the same format?

Comment: Hi JRC, Yes. Each line have the same format.

Comment: Hi Anirudh, am looking for the logic in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code does not handles any errors which can be caused by wrong input format, you can maintain it for yourself.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = new [] {
                "EUR5-002,EUR10-000,EUR20-001,EUR50-001,EUR100-001,EUR200-000,EUR500-000", 
                "EUR5-000,EUR10-000,EUR20-002,EUR50-001,EUR100-001,EUR200-000,EUR500-000", 
                "EUR5-001,EUR10-001,EUR20-002,EUR50-001,EUR100-002,EUR200-003,EUR500-000"
            };

            var results = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            foreach (var line in data)
            {
                var entries = line.Split(',');
                foreach (var entry in entries)
                {
                    var parts = entry.Split('-');
                    string key = parts[0];
                    if (!results.ContainsKey(key))
                    {
                        results[key] = 0;
                    }

                    results[key] += int.Parse(parts[1]);
                }
            }

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.Key + "-" + result.Value.ToString("000"));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tommi for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
//limit is the highest value of currency
int temp=0;
for(int x=1;x<=limit;x++,temp=0)
{
if((temp=parseDenomination(x,input))!=0)
     output+=","+"EUR"+x+"-"+temp;
}
//output has your desired output
```

---

```
private static int parseDenomination(int no,String input)
{
        return Regex.Matches(input,@"(?<=EUR"+no+@"-)\d+")
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(x=>int.Parse(x.Groups[0].Value))
                    .ToList()
                    .Sum();
}
```

Comment: Much shorter solution, but it needs to predefine currency values and will not work with not `EUR` currency. Since OP does not provide enough details maybe it will work for him.

Comment: @Tommi you are right..but op clearly mentioned  `5,10,20,50,100,200,500`

Comment: Hi Anirudh, Thanks for ur reply. Yes for now, the currency values are predefined. In future, there will be few more which we dont know exactly like 25,75 will also be there. Our logic should be work for every value.

Comment: @user2542095 edited the answer..works perfectly now as expected..

Comment: Thanks Anirudh for your extended help. I will try ur logic as well for better performance.